# Clojure is running extremely slow

Tags: performance, optimization, clojure, numbers, biginteger

I have made a simple Clojure program which is running very slow even when the number of iterations is equal to 500. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
(ns calc.core
(:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math]))

(def ^:const B 500)

(defn build-map [p h g]
  (into {} (for [n (range 0 B)] [n (mod (/ h (math/expt g n)) p)])))

(defn find-result [res-map p g]
  (for [n (range 0 B)
    :when (= (mod (math/expt g (* B n)) p) (res-map n))]
  (get res-map n)))

(defn calculate [p h g]
  (find-result (build-map p h g) p g))

(def ^:const P 130N)
(def ^:const G 642N)
(def ^:const H 323N)    

(defn -main []
  (do
    (println "Starting calculation...")
    (println (calculate P H G))
    (println "done")))
```

**UPDATE #1**
I have changed *find-result* function a bit and performance improved:

```
(defn find-result [res-map p g]
  (for [[k v] res-map
    :when (= (mod (math/expt g (* B k)) p) v)]
  v))
```

Why this code runs much faster? What other improvements could be made to my code so it runs faster (the running time is still to slow for B = 1024)?

**UPDATE #2**

Tried all of the advices and still, Clojure version seems to run forever. For example, this version written in Java runs blazingly fast: https://gist.github.com/kernelmode/e943f155edad50c01955

And here is the updated version of my code:

```
(ns crypto5.core
  (:require [clojure.math.numeric-tower :as math]))

(def ^:const B (math/expt 2N 10N))
(def ^:const P 13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084171N)
(def ^:const G 11717829880366207009516117596335367088558084999998952205599979459063929499736583746670572176471460312928594829675428279466566527115212748467589894601965568N)
(def ^:const H 3239475104050450443565264378728065788649097520952449527834792452971981976143292558073856937958553180532878928001494706097394108577585732452307673444020333N)
(def ^:const R (/ 1 G))
(def GpowB (math/expt G B))
(def exps (take B (iterate (fn [[e eb]] [(* e G) (* eb GpowB)]) [1 1])))

(defn -main []
  (println (map #(mod (/ H (first %)) P) (filter (fn [[e eb]] (= (mod (/ H e) P) (mod eb P))) exps))))
```

Comment: Given these constants, `(mod (/ h (math/expt g n)) p)` is going to be less than 1 for every n greater than 0. Is that really what you want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calculating a lot of HUGE numbers. With B being 500 your keys in the map are 0-499. In find-result with g being 642N you're calculating math/expt 500 times with the largest being (math/expt 642N 249500). This one alone takes a long time to calculate and that's just when k = 499. It would be helpful if you specified the exact problem you're trying to solve. Looks more like an algorithm problem.

**UPDATE**

I created a Clojure solution here: [Clojure solution gist](https://gist.github.com/otijhuis/b411c57b2a99e7a47168). As far as I can tell it should be the same as the Java version (better check it to be sure). It runs in about 30 seconds as well and it's much smaller and imho much more readable as well. It's ironic, I used to have a hard time reading Clojure, now it's reading Java I'm having trouble with :). The largest performance problem you had is not using modPow. Turns out that even in Java doing pow and then mod is MUCH slower than using modPow. Oh, and the Clojure BigInt isn't the same as BigInteger which doesn't make it easier. So I resorted to using BigInteger and the Java interop. Sometimes you need to to get the best performance. Hope this helps.

**UPDATE #2 THE CODE**

```
(ns calc.core)

(def start (biginteger 1))
(def b (.pow (biginteger 2) 20))
(def g (biginteger 11717829880366207009516117596335367088558084999998952205599979459063929499736583746670572176471460312928594829675428279466566527115212748467589894601965568))
(def p (biginteger 13407807929942597099574024998205846127479365820592393377723561443721764030073546976801874298166903427690031858186486050853753882811946569946433649006084171))
(def h (biginteger 3239475104050450443565264378728065788649097520952449527834792452971981976143292558073856937958553180532878928001494706097394108577585732452307673444020333))

(defn build-left-table [start end p h g]
  (into {}
        (pmap (fn [n] [(.mod(.multiply h (.modInverse (.modPow g (biginteger n) p) p)) p) (biginteger n)])
              (range start (inc end)))))

(defn find-collision [table b p g]
  (let [base (.modPow g b p)]
    (loop [i 0
           v (biginteger 1)]
      (when (< i b)
        (do
          (if (contains? table v)
               (let [percentage (double (/ (* i 100) b))]
                 (println (str "Collision after " percentage "%"))
                 [i (table v)])
               (recur (inc i) (.mod (.multiply v base) p))))))))

(time (find-collision (build-left-table start b p h g) b p g))
```

**UPDATE #3**

If you just want to find the value this is a better Clojure-like version. The above was basically a java rewrite:

```
(defn find-collision [table b p g]
  (let [base (.modPow g b p)
        f (iterate (fn [x] (.mod (.multiply x base) p)) (biginteger 1))]
    (some (fn [x] (table x)) (take b f))))
```

Comment: Yes, the numbers are huge. Actually, the target numbers P G and H will be 130 numbers long. Analogous code in Python can do all of the calculations in about 2 minutes with 130 digit numbers, so I don't think there is a problem in algorithm.

Comment: Can you show the python code with the target numbers? That will make it easier to compare.

Comment: I have linked a Gist with Java code that solves the problem in 30 seconds.

Comment: Updated the answer. Created a gist with the Clojure solution. Hope that solves your problem.

Comment: Btw, the "do" block in find-collision isn't needed. Forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

Your algorithm is O(n log n) because expt makes log n multiplications for each n. You can reduce it to O(n) writing it again in a more functional way. My recipe:

1. precalculate g^B: `(def GpowB (math/expt g B))`
2. iterate on `[1 1]` to calculate exponentials: `(def exps (take B (iterate (fn [[e eb]] [(* e G) (* eB GpowB)]) [1 1])))`
3. filter this sequence for solutions and take your result: `(map #(mod (/ H (first %)) P) (filter (fn [[e eb]] (= (mod (/H e) P) (mod eb P))) exps))`

Consider it a hint, I cannot test it by now.

In your update you get faster because you avoid a lookup in the map, calling `(res-map n)`, for each element.

Comment: Hello and thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, this code also runs forever.

Comment: The second step faster now, but the computations in step 3 are still too slow

Comment: Good point in the @OkkeTijhuis solution. So the winning choice is modPow and its use of [Chinese Reminder Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) to avoid a full pow calculation. I learned something new!